# Is it possible to exit out of only 1 loop interation in cmd prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple cmd for loop written to execute a script 10 times.

`for %1 in (1..10) DO [script]`

Is it possible to exit out of only 1 of the 10 for loops? ctrl + c terminates the entire process and ctrl + x does nothing (I'm using VSCode cmd shell if that makes any difference). Is there another method?

Comment: What's supposed to be exiting? Do you want nine iterations of the script to remain open? Do you want the loop to randomly fail 10% of the time? You haven't been very specific with your requirements.

Comment: you could script in a timed choice prior to the execution of each script within the loop to allow you to skip the execution of a given script during the iteration. See `choice /?` in cmd.exe

Comment: `for %1 in (1..10) DO [script]` is not valid [[tag:windows]] [[tag:batch-file]], or [[tag:cmd]] syntax. In cmd.exe it would be `FOR /L %I IN (1,1,10) DO [script]` and in a batch file it would be `FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,10) DO [script]`.

Comment: So it looks like `FOR /L %I IN (1,1,10) DO [script]` syntax actually worked. Now when I ctrl + c, it only exits one of the iterations. Thank you. The `for %1 in (1..10) DO [script]` syntax I was originally using also works though. I just tried it with a simple echo return and it looped 10 times.